# Problem uploading and downloading data from to deployment app in GAE

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\net\proto\ProtocolBuffer
.py", line 436, in skipData
    raise ProtocolBufferDecodeError, "corrupted"
google.net.proto.ProtocolBuffer.ProtocolBufferDecodeError: corrupted

What's the problem and how to fix it? maybe the download is not ok?

I get this error when im uploading data to my deplying app in GAE.

I use this in my app:

```
builtins:
- remote_api: on
```

command for downloading data from developement:

```
 appcfg.py download_data --application=,yapp --kind=Survey --url="http://localhost:9999/_ah/remote_api" --filename="C:\myapp\src\test.csv"
```

this is the command I use to upload data to deployment:

```
 appcfg.py upload_data --application=myapp --kind=Survey --filename="C:\myapp\src\test.csv" --url=http://myapp.appspot.com
```

myapp is not the actual name...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When uploading, the --url parameter must link to the remote_api of your application, like so:

```
 appcfg.py upload_data --application=myapp --kind=Survey --filename="C:\myapp\src\test.csv" --url=http://myapp.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api
```

Comment: I'd add one other note if you are uploading to an app you migrated over to the high replication datastore... add "s~" to the front of your application parameter value. For example, --application=s~myapp